# IS_X function synthesis

Tags: vhdl

I have some problems in synthesizing an entity which employs the function IS_X(). In particular, the message

> [Error] name IS_X is unknown

is shown.
Is it synthesizable?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FF2 is
    generic(XOUT, XNOUT: std_logic);
    port(   INPUT, CLK: in std_logic;
            OUTPUT, NOUTPUT: out std_logic
    );
end entity FF2;

architecture behavioral of FF2 is

    signal temp : std_logic := '0';
    begin
        FUNC:process(CLK)
        begin
            if(CLK'event and rising_edge(CLK)) then
                temp <= INPUT;
            end if;
        end process FUNC;

        OUTPUT <= XOUT when is_x(temp) else temp;
        NOUTPUT <= XNOUT when is_x(temp) else (not temp);

end architecture behavioral;
```

Comment: is_x has no meaning for hardware, as INPUT will always be '0' or '1'. IS this just for a simulation thing? what synth tool is it? You could just use when temp = 'X' instead of is_x function. Also - why are you using clk'event and rising_edge(clk). Rising_edge function already checks for a 'event. Usual form i clk'event and clk='1'   OR rising_edge(clk), not both.

Comment: IS_X is defined in IEEE package std_logic_1164,  and tests  for 'U', 'W', 'X', '–'. IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.2.4.4 Metalogical values in relational expressions "If the VHDL source code includes an equality operator (=) for which one operand is a static metalogical value and for which the other operand is not a static value, a synthesis tool shall interpret the equality relation as equivalent to the BOOLEAN value FALSE...." (a case expression choice is evaluated with an equality operator here). What tool/version?  Is  the equivalent `OUTPUT <= TO_XO1(temp);` supported?

Comment: Because is_x() is testing for signal for undefined values like 'U', 'W', 'X' and '–'. This is not synthesizable because there is not hardware equivalent to determine this. Use other signal value to determine your signal state instead. Same method applies to high impedance 'Z' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by synthesizable?   Using is_x to create hardware should not be supported by a synthesis tool since in hardware there is only 0 and 1, and after synthesis there is nothing that can be created for your code:

```
OUTPUT <= XOUT when is_x(temp) else temp;
NOUTPUT <= XNOUT when is_x(temp) else (not temp);
```

OTOH, using is_x in a report statement should be ignored by your synthesis tool (meaning a supported use of is_x to report simulation issues) as it does not create any hardware:

```
assert not(is_x(temp)) report "captured X on input" severity error;
```

This is helpful for debug, particularly in statemachine where there is lots of X masking.   If your synthesis tool does not accept this, be sure to submit it as a bug to the vendor - and report them here.